# weight paint falloff acting like its full red

Tags: animation, mesh, uv, weight-painting, error

I'm making a ballista kind of weapon and for the string, I use bone and weight paint to pull it back.

But when I paint it the mesh doesn't register the falloff so it acts like the whole gradient is red[image: gradient]

I hope this help with seeing the problem.

[image]
with bones on

What can I do to fix this?

UPDATE: BlenderFile: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1aK0xTaL3XNXggw6F0KdVbHLpXWArTnfO?usp=sharing

Video: https://youtu.be/jvdLWzFbRTw

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, try subdividing the string a few times. If you only have vertices at each end and in the centre of the string, you won't see any falloff over its length.

Comment: i think without a blend file we can just guess and it's hard to tell what the reason is.

Comment: Not quite clear, to me.. if the string is the short, currently straight line at the center of your illustration, a gradient is visible on it.

Comment: @Chris I put a google drive with the blend file! and a youtube video for more explanation

Comment: @JohnEason it got subdivisions and it worked with an earlier armature but because of some other problems I did it over and now this

Comment: @Dadarius1996 I got it the wrong way round. - You should try dissolving all ten edge loops along the string to remove the subdivisions and see if that fixes it. You also currently have Auto Keying turned on in the header of the Timeline which may be confusing the issue.

Comment: @JohnEason Thank you! That worked, so simple a bit ashamed that I didn't think about that

Comment: Good! Glad that it worked. I was a bit confused about all the talk about weight painting until I saw the blend file.